# Net Core Project with Microsoft Access Database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ms-access-2010, asp.net-core-2.0

I just created a net core project, where I need to connect to an Access database using EF. I downloaded a nugget package called JetEntityFramework.

This is my appsettings.json

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=pasman; Password=root;  Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=Todo; Integrated Security=true; Pooling=true;",
    "AccessConnection": "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\DBAccess.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234;"

  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This is my model configuration

```
public class ClientConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
    { 
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Client> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(prop => prop.ClientCode);

            builder.Property(prop => prop.ListCode).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(prop => prop.CodeResp).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(prop => prop.CodePassport).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(prop => prop.Name).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(prop => prop.Surname).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(prop => prop.Adress).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(prop => prop.City).IsRequired();


            builder.Property(prop => prop.Country).IsRequired();


        }
    }
```

This is my model

```
 public class Client
    {
        public int ClientCode{ get; set; }

        public int ListCode{ get; set; }

        public string CodeResp{ get; set; }

        public string CodePassport{ get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public string Surname{ get; set; }

        public string Adress{ get; set; }

        public string City{ get; set; }



        public string Country{ get; set; }
    }
```

This is my client Context

```
public class ClientContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Client> Client{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseJet(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\DBAccess.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234");
        }

        public ClientContext( DbContextOptions<ClienteContext> options): base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
        =>modelbuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration());


}
```

This is my startup class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);



            services.AddTransient<JetProviderServices>();




        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm new at this, all i want to do is access to my access db, and make a query to get all clients but i dont know how to do this. In my Startup Class i think that i need to add my configuration connection like i do with entity using postgresql

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext <ClienteContext>(options =>
                               options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AccessConnection")
                                 ));
```

Excuse me if I'm writing badly.

Comment: I highly recommend you avoid use Access as your database.  [LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) is in all instances a better solution.

Comment: I already know that you try to discourage to use this type of database. But what I have to achieve is to access the access db, and then once the data is mapped, save them in a posgresql database

Comment: Having worked with MS Access DB's in .NET (specifically, DAO 3.6) which only *kind of* works with JET, I can feel your pain. It may be less a less painful route if it's feasible for you to export the access db to CSV, and map the CSV to your Pgsql db.

Comment: The NuGet you mention is for EF6, not EF Core.

Comment: If this is for conversion only, why don't you use .Net 4,5.x in combination with EF6?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg 
Could you give me steps to follow these instructions? 

In addition to this, eventually, in addition to obtaining data from the access database, I will need to store things there.

Comment: I could connect to Access Database by creating this connection

   con.ConnectionString = @"Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=C:\Database\AccessTest.accdb;defaultdir=C:\Database;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin";


But i cant make a successfull conection if my access database has a password in it.